# Is there a queue dictionary for a GCD queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am quite fond of the `threadDictionary` property in `NSThread`: very handy to store things with per-thread ownership.

Is there an equivalent dictionary for a GCD queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into `dispatch_set_context/dispatch_get_context`.  Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html). You have to manage the context but it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you can target iOS 5 and above, you can use `dispatch_queue_get[set]_specific()` which allows you to add dictionary-style (i.e. keyed) values to a queue.  I can't find the document pages on them, strangely enough, but they are commented in `queue.h`