# Equivalent on Objective C/Swift of Java ThreadLocal Variables

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, swift, multithreading

In Java, we have the `ThreadLocal` class:

> This class provides thread-local variables.  These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its  `get` or `set` method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. `ThreadLocal` instances are typically `private static` fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

Example:

```java
private static final ThreadLocal<StringBuilderHelper>
    threadLocalStringBuilderHelper = new ThreadLocal<StringBuilderHelper>() {
        @Override
        protected StringBuilderHelper initialValue() {
            return new StringBuilderHelper();
        }
    };
```

Is there any equivalent in Objective C or Swift to simulate this behavior? Can i just use on Swift:

```
static let String = someInitialValue()
```

and achieve the same goal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread-Local storage and iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557768/thread-local-storage-and-ios)

Comment: Are you sure you want threads and not GCD? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962850/is-there-a-queue-dictionary-for-a-gcd-

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at `NSThread threadDictionary`. I believe this is roughly the same thing.

A typical use in Objective-C might be:

```
NSMutableDictionary *threadData = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
threadData[someKey] = someObject; // write

someObject = threadData[someKey]; // read
```